# Search Within Array Object in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, search, swift

I have an array of restaurants that are objects with name, type, location, etc. How can I search for just a restaurant name, or just a location without searching the entire array object?

For example my array with 2 Restaurant objects. I only want to search if Name contains "United". If i search the entire object, both will show up because of the country.

```
[<Restaurant: 0x7fcb0ad80950, objectId: LA74J92QDA, localId: (null)> {
    City = "New York";
    Country = "United States";
    Name = United Bakery;
    RestaurantLoc = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x7fcb0af6cbc0, latitude: 40.759212, longitude: -73.984632>";
    State = NY;
    Street = "1 main st.";
    Zipcode = 10055;
}, <Restaurant: 0x7fcb0af6cfc0, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46, localId: (null)> {
    City = "New York";
    Country = "United States";
    Name = Wendys Bakery;
    RestaurantLoc = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x7fcb0af6cd60, latitude: 40.759210, longitude: -73.984631>";
    State = NY;
    Street = "1 main st.";
    Zipcode = 10055;
}]
```

This is the block that creates the array of objects:

```
            let userGeoPoint = currentLocGeoPoint
            var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurant")
            query.whereKey("RestaurantLoc", nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint, withinMiles:50)
            query.limit = 2

            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (object: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if object != nil {
                    println(object)
                } else {
                    println("The getObject request failed with error: \(error)")
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`. Here is the small example:

```
NSString *searchString = @"a";
NSArray *filteredProducts = [products filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString]];
```

Swift:

```
let searchString = "text_to_search"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString);
let filteredArray = array.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate!);
```

Comment: He said in swift not in Objective - C

Comment: @Leena what a problem to use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` in swift?

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko I mean to say the question was related to swift so the answer should be in swift instead of Objective-C......

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko Thank you for the example. I tried using filteredArrayUsingPredicate but ran into this error in swift `'[AnyObject]' does not have a member named 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate'`

Comment: @Rachel I think this is because object, which you try to `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` isn't NSArray object, but something another...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use filter(_:) function. From Apple Developer:

```
Returns an array containing the elements of the array for which a provided closure indicates a match.

Use this method to return a new array by filtering an existing array. The closure that you supply for includeElement: should return a Boolean value to indicate whether an element should be included (true) or excluded (false) from the final collection
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html

Comment: Thanks, i read through it. But can the filter function be used to find if "Name" contains "xxx" or "yyy"? Would you mind providing a short example?